# automatically kick off a few thread dumps when CPU usage is over a threshold for certain time?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, jboss, cpu-usage

We have a Java 1.6 web application, deployed to JBoss 5.0.1, that occasionally runs into this very high CPU usage and stuck there. It is very hard to capture and we have not been able to reproduce this problem with our tests at all. The thread dumps we created after the CPU usage already high are not very informative, as you can imagine.

The server is centos 5.7. I am just wondering if I can set up a watch/trigger that when CPU usage is over >50%, say, for continuously >5 seconds or so, a process is started to create a handful of thread dumps of the problematic process at a 2-second interval.

Hope I explain it well. Any hints/suggestions would be deeply appeciated.

Comment: which JRE ? OpenJDK or Oracle ?

Comment: Oracle. HotSpot 64 bit